# inserting page break in word using excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro that copies data from excel into word.   I can't get the macro to insert a page break after I just copied the range of cells into word.  I get the following error

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I am guessing this happens because the copied data in Word is still highlighted  and I need to get a cursor at the bottom of the new copied date before I try to insert a page break.

How do I do this?

This is a section of the code that is not working - actually the last line of the code but I thought I should show you right before as well:

```
        Range("A1:F25").Select
         Selection.Copy

         appWD.Documents.Add

         appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
         DoEvents


        appWD.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```

Comment: What type of object is appWD?

Comment: I defined appWD as follows:
Dim appWD As Object                                               Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
With appWD.Selection
    .Collapse Direction:=0
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
End With
```

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertbreak(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.collapse(v=office.14).aspx

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Error-9118-protect-Docu-t1123894.html

Comment: I tried but I received Run-rime error'9118': Parameter value was out of acceptable range at the line appWD.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

Comment: It looks like it didn't put the collapse at the beginning but I did get a cursor at the beginning of the copied data.

Comment: Interesting, I would think the cursor would go after it. We'll get to that once we figure out the .InsertBreak though. It's been a while since I toyed with anything in VBA, try, .InsertBreak(wdPageBreak) possibly?

Comment: Read this article here, http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Error-9118-protect-Docu-t1123894.html, looks like it could possibly be an issue with using the wdCollapseEnd/wdPageBreak types. Try using the enum values instead. Also, it looks like the default values is pagebreak so you could probably do without saying Type:=wdPageBreak altogether. I've dited my response.

Comment: I will read the article.  I tried your previous comment and it didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't had the chance to update my answer, I just edited it, try it with that.

Comment: It worked and it even inserted the break after the pasted data even though it looked like the cursor was before the data.  Thank you so much for your help.  I am new to this forum.  how do I mark you as answering my question

Comment: There should be a check mark to the left of my answer. Glad I could help!